# How to create transaction handling by only using servlets and jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I had tried to terminate that by myself, but i can't.
I need to save objects in multiple relative tables of my database and it must be in one single transaction.
I am using Servlets, JSP, JDBC.
(already have the dao layer and service layer)
As we know, the transactions always must to be in the service layer.

When I was using Spring MVC, I always used this annotation in services:

```
@Transactional
```

and had options for TransactionManager in my spring.xml
Now I need to do the same with servlets.
Can anyone help me with some small example for servlets transactions or maybe somebody have suggestive thoughts for this?

Comment: My recommendation is have a spring managed service that does that for you, I think it's very unlikely for you to truly want a single transaction per request spanning all your application layers. You can then retrieve that bean from your context via WebApplicationContextUtils

Comment: Hi MahdeTo, most of my operations with database are relative to each other and must to be transaction... about spring managed service: in my current task i need to made the transaction handling by myself (no using spring or something)...trying to find some example... but no luck..

Comment: Are you using Servlets instead of Spring Controllers because of performance reasons or is Spring not available at all?

Comment: Hi  Fritz Duchardt, this is my task. You are right, Spring is not available at all... I am using servlets in controllers.  JDBC on dao layer.
No Spring at all. In my case it would be very simple
Thats why i can't use this annotation @Transactional and i must to do some transactionManager by myself.

Comment: If you want to handle the transaction boundaries manually use a TransactionTemplate or a JDBCTemplate maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different ways to manage transactions at JDBC level.

The simplest way, is a filter: you open a transaction at the beginning or the request processing and commit (or rollback) it at the end. It is as little invasive as possible in other layers, but you cannot have the transaction demarcation at the service layer.

At the opposite, you can add code to explicitely create and commit transactions in all (relevant) service methods. You can put real code in common methods to limit code duplication, but you will have to consistently modify all your service layer.

An alternate way, as you have an existant service layer, would be to mimic Spring and use proxies around your service classes. The proxies would open create transaction, call the real method and commit the transaction. IMHO, it would still be a little invasive method with little code duplication.

My choice would be to use method 1 for very simple use cases or prototyping and method 3 for more serious ones - but this is just my opinion.

Comment: Thanks you very much, yes this is what i need.

Answer (score 1):

On your Service Method you should handle transaction yourself, you'll find below an example:

```
        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();

            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            // do your database work preparedStatement Insert, Update 


            //OR                
            // If you are doing your work on DAO you can pass connection to your DAO                
            //XDao  xDao  = new XDao(dbConnection);
            //YDao yDao = new YDao(dbConnection);

            //xDao.doWork();
            //yDao.doWork()  

            dbConnection.commit();

            System.out.println("Done!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            dbConnection.rollback();

        } finally {

            //Close prepared statements


            //close connection
            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }
```

For advanced Pattern and uderstanding, I recommend this blog post [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-persistence/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you need to understand which specification you would like to work with and then figure out how to do the integration.

There are so many techniques and technologies in Java to access the database.

In general if you want to access the DB at the lowest layer (JDBC) you'll have to manage transactions by yourself.

[This link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/sql/jdbc-transaction-management-example/) can be useful, because it provides a lot of examples. In general you have `setAutoCommit(false)' and then`rollback/commit`on`Connection` jdbc interface.

If you wish to use stuff like hibernate (note, you still don't need spring for this) - the Transaction inteface can be handy.
Here is the [Example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-transaction-handle-example/)

Spring as an integration framework allows using transaction management by means of definition of relevant beans, so you kind of chose by yourself which transaction management technology should be used.

This is a broad topic, you might be interested to read [This](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) to understand more the spring way to manage transactions.

In general, JDBC is the most low level of accessing the database in java, all other APIs are built on top of it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Mark Bramnik, about jdbc transactions a have already understand, thanks to your answer. But i can't to use spring. In my task i must to handle transactions by myselft only using servlets and all work with transactions must to be in the service layer.

Comment: Sure, its ok, I just wanted to provide a brief and 'general' overview of some transaction maangement techniques in java. If you don't use spring, and have to handle transactions by yourself, go with JDBC way :)

Comment: Thanks Mark, i will :)